# Ошибка чтения файла блокировки /My_file/.main.cpp.swp: недостаточно данных для чтения

Tags: linux, debian

Я получил такую ошибку при открытии файла `/My_file/.main.cpp` открывал с помощью программы nano.

```
Error reading lock file /My_file/.main.cpp.swp: Not enough data read
```

Как мне это исправить ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо удалить скрытый файл. `.[Твой_файл].swp`, который хранится в той же папке что и файл который я пытаюсь открыть.

Надо воспользоваться командой shell-a и удалить этот скрытый файл командой

```
# rm /My_file/.main.cpp.swp
```

Эта проблема возникает в nano 2.7.4 (по крайней мере у меня такая версия) и должна быть связана с тем, как nano обрабатывает поврежденный файл подкачки. Хотя её она бывает связана с нехваткой памяти.